no such option: --platform linux-x86-64 when running pip install --platform
I get an error:

no such option: --platform linux-x86-64

when using:
python -m pip install --platform linux-x86-64.
python -m pip --version shows 24.2.
python -m pip install --help shows --platform argument in the list.
I can't find literally any results on Google, is there anything I am doing fundamentally wrong?
For context full command looks like this:
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt --only-binary=:all: --target ./python_example_app --platform linux-x86_64

How are you running the command? Are you using a terminal shell (if so, which one?) or something else? Is that the command exactly how you are typing it? I am having issues reproducing this error.

@sytech I am running it in a spawned shell. It is a Github Actions workflow. In fact, all commands above a ran in the same way, version returns version, help returns help while platform just crashes.

@Telion it looks like there's a problem with how you are passing the arguments. --platform linux-x86_64 is being treated as a single argument, it seems (as if quoted, for example). So if you are using something like subprocess.run you need to make sure that the --platform flag and its argument (linux-x86_64) are passed as separate arguments in the shell. If you have code or a GitHub Actions file you're using, please edit the question to include this.

@sytech that actually might be the issue, let me check that, thank you!

@sytech you were right. I couldn't understand either why it referenced argument along with its value as unknown option. That's why! I had both argument and the value concatenated before spawning command, they were used as a single argument. You've saved some of my sanity. Mind leaving an answer to this question? I'd like to accept that as an answer.


no such option: --platform linux-x86-64

This error message implies that the entire string --platform linux-x86-64 is being treated as a single argument. The --platform flag and its argument value (linux-x86_64) should be passed as separate arguments.
This may occur, for example, if you run the command in a shell with this full argument in quotes. To fix this, make sure the flag and its argument are passed separately, (for example, without quotes) as you have written in your question.
$ pip install [...] "--platform linux-x86_64"  # Bad
# no such option: --platform linux-x86_64

$ pip install [...] --platform linux-x86_64  # Good

The same principle applies if this command is invoked via something like subprocess.run or similar kind of exec call. You should ensure that the --platform flag and its respective argument are passed separately.
Alternatively, flags and their values can be passed as a single argument when using the form of key=value for example:
pip install [...] "--platform=linux-x86_64" # this is OK too

